# Detect UserMedia Permission Before Requesting It

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, user-experience, getusermedia

I'd like to explain to users why the camera/microphone is needed before asking them, so that they can make a better choice if they want to grant it or not.

In order to implement that **I need a way to detect if the permission has previously been granted**, so that I can explain the request to the user before actually asking them. I also don't want to ask everytime (even though I already have permissions!).

Answer (score 14):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => 
  devices.forEach(device => console.log(device.label)))
```

When not yet permitted device.label == ""
When permitted device.label != ""

Comment: Will this work if no devices are detected? Is there any documentation for this being guaranteed to work?

Comment: Yes, If no devices this method can not be used.  I dont know documentation.

Comment: If it returns no devices, then there's nothing to ask permission for, so that's fine. But note that labels show if ***either*** camera ***or*** microphone have been granted, so some users may still get prompted. Also, in browsers other than Chrome you'll still bug users every time this way, except those who've explicitly opted in to give you persistent access. Also, this is likely to break in the future, as I mention in another answer.

Comment: so [for microphone detection] something like `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => devices.some(val => val.kind === "audioinput" && val.label !== "" )).then(function(result) { console.log("result", result)})`

Answer (score 7):

Use a cookie or `localStorage` to remember that you've asked them before and gotten a yes.

Some browsers let users grant permission for each use of the camera or microphone so if your metric is you don't want to ask them every time, then don't tie your message to whether you've been granted permanent access.

The `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` trick mentioned in another answer presently detects persistent permission to camera ***and/or*** microphone fairly well - but you don't know which one or whether you've been granted both.

Also, this may break over time, as the spec was updated recently to untie the access to labels from the persistent access of camera and/or microphone, in part to support single-use permission use-cases better. Once browsers update to the spec, it would no longer imply persistent camera and/or microphone permission in those situations.

The long-term answer to whether permission has been persisted is to use [`query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query), but as you can see from running this, browsers don't support it yet for `"camera"` and `"microphone"` (or in some cases at all):

```js
navigator.permissions.query({name: "camera"})
.then(({state}) => console.log(state),
      e => console.log(e.name +": "+ e.message));
```

Comment: I hope this specification will be implemented soon.

Comment: I hope it won't be misused to force users into granting persistent permissions by treating them to nonoptimal workflows for first-time visitors until they do. As a user I prefer to retain control of exactly when my camera and microphone turn on.

Comment: `navigator.permissions.query` returns a promise which resolves to an object with `state` not `status`.

Comment: @EvanBacon Looks like the spec [changed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus) since I posted this. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning permissions.query. I'd never heard of that before and it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @BryceJohnson Sigh, please read my answer for why query is a bad idea. Not all browsers persist permission as willingly as Chrome, so you'll be unnecessarily priming repeat visitors in those browsers. Firefox does not implement query for camera and microphone for this very reason. Just use `localStorage`.

Comment: @jib yeah, I saw that. I'm working on an enterprise application that doesn't  have to support browsers other than chrome. So it works for me.

Comment: @BryceJohnson Chrome supports `localStorage` like any other browser last I checked.

Comment: If my browser support requirements allow me to use `permissions.query` it's obviously preferable. There are all sorts of ways using a flag in localstorage to track whether you have device permissions can be error-prone and add complexity, compared to just asking the browser whether I have permission *now*.